# Probability My Teacher Will Post on Facebook Today

Tags: probability, statistics

I love the things my Multivariable Calculus teacher posts on Facebook. I wanna know what's the chance I can look forward to another post by him today, or perhaps within the next hour.

For example, he made 3 posts yesterday, and 5 posts the day before. I have a sense I want to take a big average of these, but how can I find the probability from that? Do I make that the mean of some statistical model?

I know it's kind of a fuzzy question, or maybe it's obvious, but I'd be very happy to hear your thoughts on how you'd approach this problem.

Comment: Get the timestamps of all of the posts and look at the distribution of time in-between posts. It will probably look something like an exponential distribution which has parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: @flinty Very interesting idea!! Instead of the full time stamp would just knowing the dates be enough? 
What about a Poisson distribution with average number of posts per day as the rate?

Comment: I think the question is off topic on math.se, because psycho-social factors, the teacher's schedule, time of year (January break, summer, less likely).  There are too many factors, some qualitative that aren't operationalizable, or are subject to researchers assignment of value.  Too much room for researcher's bias, faulty design, human guess-work....

Comment: @amWhy I disagree, the efficacy of any mathematical model depends on your assumptions. Whether your assumptions are good or not is up to the OP. You can definitely develop a good model for this if you are willing to make assumptions that limit the scope enough

Comment: Then there's "mood of teacher", whether the teacher's schedule includes dropping off or picking up children, or stopping to shop for an ingredient needed.  Whether they had an argument with their spouse...

Comment: @amWhy, still, that doesn't mean that you can't create a model that will *to some degree* capture the situation and make *good enough* predictions

Comment: Assume ing makes an "ass out of u and me"

Comment: @amWhy I guess mathematics is full of asses then :D

Comment: A very rough estimate can be given using the sample mean and sample variance and using Cantelli's inequality